# PHP Pagination Truncate List of Pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

Update to include full code.

I am pulling records from a database and then displaying them 5 per page like this:

```
$num_rec_per_page=5;

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1;   }; 

$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
$school = $_REQUEST['school'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `school` LIKE '%$school%'";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
};
```

This gives me a long list like this for each page:

```
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
<Prev 1 2 3 4....53 54 55 Next>
```

Comment: From where these `<prev` and `next>` came? Is it a link?

Comment: Anyway, to generate the numeric links as per the desired behavior, all you need is one space. So your echo statement should be like this, `echo " <a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/DNCVu youre welcome

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - that's the issue; the user is currently getting the full list of links, and wants instead a few links which will shift based on where in the pagination we are. Unfortunately, it's too broad, and hence off topic.

Comment: @andrewsi yeah, and the code is also not sufficient to support the question.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Sorry about that -- just updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses in your `SELECT` query to implement pagination.

Here's the reference:

- [PHP Limit Data Selections From MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

So your code should be like this:

```
$num_rec_per_page = 5;

if(isset($_GET["page"])){ 
    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
}else{ 
    $page=1;  
} 

$offset = ($page - 1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
$school = $_GET['school'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `school` LIKE '%" . $school. "%' LIMIT 5 OFFSET " . $offset;
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){ 
    if($i != 1){
        $prev_page = $i - 1;
        echo "<a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=" . $prev_page ."'>&lt;prev</a>";
    }
    echo " <a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    if($i != $total_pages){
        $next_prev = $i + 1;
        echo " <a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=" . $next_page ."'>next&gt;</a>";
    }
}
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).